# How i can prevent safari on iOS to replace triangle with iOS UI?

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, ios-ui-automation

I use triangles ◀ ▶ as button in my application.

```
<div>◀</div>
<div>▶</div>
<div>✔</div>
```

It works fine in all browsers, except on Safari for iOS, where the triangles are replaced by safari UI elements.

If you see the fiddles with a browser you can see normal triangles, but if you check with iOS Safari will appeare safari UI.

http://codepen.io/sassoli/pen/KNgyKe

I know, i can solve simply using border triangles or images, but I prefer a solution with css.

#### Edit

I find out that  this char `✔` also is replaced with iOS UI.

Comment: You might be better using an icon font - http://fontawesome.io/

Comment: yep i know... but in this case i'm searching for a solution with these triangles.

Comment: if you replace them with their entities `&#x25b6;` and `&#x25c0;` the issue still remains? and if you put them as pseudoelements?

Comment: I tried with entities and using as content in  pseudolements, but the issue remains...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that these chars are not replaced by iOS

Right-triangle: ► (&#x25ba)

Left-triangle: ◄ (&#x25c4)

or as alternative, is possible use psedoselector adding "\FE0E"

HTML:

```
<span class="left-pointing-triangle">&nbsp;</span>
<span class="right-pointing-triangle">&nbsp;</span>
```

CSS:

```
.left-pointing-triangle::after {
   content: "\25C0 \FE0E";
}

.right-pointing-triangle::after {
   content: "\25B6 \FE0E";
}
```